# How many output files are created after an MR Job in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a file which is less than (very less) default block size. The output from my Mapper is a large number of `<key,list<values>>` pairs (greater than 20).

I read somewhere that the number of output files generated after an MR job is equal to the number of reducers which in my case are greater than 20. But I got a single file in the output.

Then I made `job.setNumReduceTasks(2)` hoping that it would generate two files in the output. But it still generated a single file.

So can I conclude that the number of output files is equal to the number of blocks?

And also, is one block of data fed to one Mapper?

Comment: Your mapper output contains greater than 20 keys right?

Comment: Yes. 20 different keys.

Answer (score 3):

**- Block - A Physical Division:**

HDFS was designed to hold and manage large amounts of data.
 A **default block size is 64 MB**. That means if a 128-MB text file was put in to HDFS, HDFS would divide the file into two blocks *(128 MB/64 MB)* and distribute the two chunks to the data nodes in the cluster.

**- Split - A Logical Division:**

When Hadoop submits jobs, it splits the input data logically and process by each Mapper. Split is only a reference. Split has details in `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputSplitand` rules (how to split) decided by getSplits() in class `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Input.FileInputFormat`.

> By default, the size of split = block size = 64M.

Now consider your block size is 64MB. The file which you are processing should be greater than 64MB to create its physical splits. If it is less than 64 MB then you will see only single file as you mentioned in your output. (No matter how many key-value your mapper will produce!)

Comment: So to conclude, number of output files is equal to number of blocks, right?

Comment: Yes. Considering the default case. If you have block size 64MB and file size 128MB then you will get 2 input chunks and 2 output files.
You can check your block size using http://localhost:50070/dfshealth.html#tab-overview  if you haven't manually changed any port numbers